# checking single value in multiple tables and check response

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, relational-database

I have one mysql table `mv4w_campaign_delivery_log` From where i will get Subscriber_id then check it in three other tables

```
mv4w_campaign_track_open
mv4w_campaign_track_unsubscribe
mv4w_campaign_track_url
```

If the subscriber_id is present in the above table then i receive true otherwise false....

**for example**
Subscriber id is present in mv4w_campaign_track_open table but not in other two tables so i will recivie only true for this not for other two tables they will be respond with false ..

how can i write query for this ? i am very confused study joins and other things but still confused please help . you can ask for table database schema in message please help me

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways and depends on what you desired format is whether it be columns or rows as well as other things.  But here is an example of how you can use left join with a case statement to see if their is a related record in your log table.  In the future when asking questions show us what you try!

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    l.Subscriber_id
    ,CASE WHEN o.Subscriber_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as ExistsInOpen
    ,CASE WHEN un.Subscriber_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as ExistsInUnsubscrib
    ,CASE WHEN u.Subscriber_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as ExistsInUrl
FROM
    mv4w_campaign_delivery_log l
    LEFT JOIN mv4w_campaign_track_open o
    ON l.Subscriber_id = o.Subscriber_id
    LEFT JOIN mv4w_campaign_track_unsubscribe un
    ON l.Subscriber_id = un.Subscriber_id
    LEFT JOIN mv4w_campaign_track_url
    ON l.Subscriber_id = u.Subscriber_id
```